# How do you video call on Windows Live Messenger 2011?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, video-chat

I have 2 computers here in the same room that I am trying to set up to use video calling. However, the "video call" option is disabled in the main menu on both machines (alt key>Tools>Video>Start a video Call). I have configured both machines to use both audio and video on the current machine (all appears to be working), and set up the video wizard through Windows Live Messenger.

One problem I noticed is that I am logging into my account and the other machine is logged into my girlfriend's account. For some reason, she appears under the "Facebook" heading even though she is logged in through Windows Live Messenger.

This used to be really trivial in previous versions of MSN messenger. I don't understand why this is so much more complicated now. So how do you get a video conversation going?

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions on Microsoft's Live community get a response from MS telling them the video button (and others at times) may be disabled if the client is unable to get a response from the server it's connected to regarding that particular service.

They recommend signing out of Windows Live and then back in, which may force it to reconnect to the server and hopefully get the correct information on available services.

If signing out and back in does not work, manually closing the entire program (not just minimizing it to the task bar) and then restarting it may help.

Solutions derived from here:
http://windowslivehelp.com/thread.aspx?threadid=d056d70f-df37-4cde-bd9d-510c101fb4bd

Other possible solutions to try:
http://windowslivehelp.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=2f68d6f8-9049-4b14-b2fc-f191f489c938